# How to split an XML file (into several other files) properly once a certain tag has been found?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

The problem:

I am trying to split the XML  by re-writing it once a tag has been found. However the result doesn't come out properly because while iterating through elements and then adding them into a new ET, it is not copying their children. The children are eventually added once the iter has passed by that element, so even if I found the way to copy the children once added to the new ET, it would end up being a duplicate.

What I have tried:

I have tried to do so parsing the XML with lxml's ElementTree and then iterating through the elements.

If the element's tag doesn't match, the element is then recorded into an ET object and then using tostring to write it down. Once the element iterated matches the tag that I want the XML to split at, it will change the file's name and effectively 'split' by recording it into a new file.

```
from lxml import etree as ET

parser = ET.XMLParser()
context = ET.parse('activity-list(2).xml', parser=parser)
index = 0
root = context.getroot()

new_data = ET.Element('iati-activity')

for elem in context.iter('iati-activity'):
    for element in list(elem.iter()):
        if element.tag == 'iati-identifier':
            print("PASSED HERE")
            index = index + 1
        filename = format(str(index) + ".xml")
        print("ELEMENT IS", element.tag)
        new_sub = ET.SubElement(new_data, element.tag, attrib = 
        element.attrib)
        new_sub.text = element.text 
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(ET.tostring(new_data))
```

**EDIT** --

XML Structure (INPUT):

```
<iati-activities version="2.03>
    <iati-activity>
       <iati-identifier>
          <title>
               <narrative>
               </narrative>
          </title>
       </iati-identifier>
       <iati-identifier>
          <title>
               <narrative>
               </narrative>
          </title>
       </iati-identifier>
    </iati-activity>
</iati-activities>
```

XML Structure (OUTPUT - CURRENT)

```
<iati-activities version="2.03>
    <iati-activity>
       <iati-identifier>
          <title>
          </title>
          <narrative>
          </narrative>
       </iati-identifier>
    </iati-activity>
</iati-activities>

... Same structure is created in second file with next iati-identifier's data
```

Current input:

```
<iati-activity>
    <iati-identifier>XM-DAC-6-4-011077</iati-identifier>
    <reporting-org ref="XM-DAC-6-4" type="10" secondary-reporter="0">
      <narrative xml:lang="it">AICS - Agenzia Italiana per la Cooperazione allo Sviluppo</narrative>
      <narrative>Italian Agency for Development Cooperation</narrative>
    </reporting-org>
    <title>
      <narrative>Protracted relief and recovery operation</narrative>
      <narrative xml:lang="it">Protracted relief and recovery operation </narrative>
    </title>
    <description>
      <narrative>Protracted relief and recovery operation</narrative>
    </description>
    <description>
      <narrative xml:lang="it">Protracted relief and recovery operation </narrative>
    </description>
    <participating-org ref="XM-DAC-6-4" type="10" role="1">
      <narrative>AICS - Italian Agency for Cooperation and Development</narrative>
    </participating-org>
    <other-identifier ref="011077" type="A1">
      <owner-org ref="XM-DAC-6-4">
        <narrative>AICS</narrative>
      </owner-org>
    </other-identifier>
    <activity-status code="2"/>
    <activity-date iso-date="2017-05-01" type="1"/>
    <activity-date iso-date="2018-04-30" type="3"/>
    <contact-info type="1">
      <organisation>
        <narrative>AICS - Italian Agency for Cooperation and Development</narrative>
      </organisation>
      <telephone>+ 39 06 32492 305</telephone>
      <email>info@aics.gov.it</email>
      <mailing-address>
        <narrative>via Salvatore Contarini 25, 00135 Roma</narrative>
      </mailing-address>
    </contact-info>
    <recipient-country code="SO" percentage="100.00"/>
    <location>
      <location-reach code="1"/>
      <location-id/>
      <point/>
    </location>
    <collaboration-type code="3"/>
    <related-activity ref="XM-DAC-6-4-011077-01-0" type="2"/>
    <iati-identifier>XM-DAC-6-4-011077-01-0</iati-identifier>
    <reporting-org ref="XM-DAC-6-4" type="10" secondary-reporter="0">
      <narrative xml:lang="it">AICS - Agenzia Italiana per la Cooperazione allo Sviluppo</narrative>
      <narrative>Italian Agency for Development Cooperation</narrative>
    </reporting-org>
    <title>
      <narrative>Protracted relief and recovery operation</narrative>
      <narrative xml:lang="it">Protracted relief and recovery operation</narrative>
    </title>
    <description>
      <narrative>The scope of the program is to support the population on food security and resilience. In particular, to support local agricultural products and vulnerable families on food security.</narrative>
    </description>
    <description>
      <narrative xml:lang="it">Contributo al PAM per il programma per la sicurezza alimentare e la resilienza. Le attività, che con programmi analoghi sono state realizzate già negli scorsi anni includono oltre al tradizionale aiuto alimentare, anche il sostegno alle attività generatrici di reddito, la realizzazione di infrastrutture, il sostegno ai produttori agricoli locali e il sostegno alle famiglie più vulnerabili, per l’acquisto di beni alimentari e non, nel mercato locale attraverso smartcard prepagate che includono anche i dati biometrici dei beneficiari</narrative>
    </description>
    <participating-org ref="XM-DAC-6-4" type="10" role="1">
      <narrative>AICS - Italian Agency for Cooperation and Development</narrative>
    </participating-org>
    <participating-org ref="41140" type="40" role="4">
      <narrative>WFP - WORLD FOOD PROGRAMME</narrative>
    </participating-org>
    <other-identifier ref="011077/01/0" type="A1">
      <owner-org ref="XM-DAC-6-4">
        <narrative>AICS</narrative>
      </owner-org>
    </other-identifier>
    <activity-status code="2"/>
    <activity-date iso-date="2017-05-02" type="1"/>
    <activity-date iso-date="2018-04-30" type="3"/>
    <contact-info type="1">
      <organisation>
        <narrative>AICS - Italian Agency for Cooperation and Development</narrative>
      </organisation>
      <telephone>+ 39 06 32492 305</telephone>
      <email>info@aics.gov.it</email>
      <mailing-address>
        <narrative>via Salvatore Contarini 25, 00135 Roma</narrative>
      </mailing-address>
    </contact-info>
    <recipient-country code="SO" percentage="100.00"/>
    <sector code="52010" vocabulary="1" percentage="100.00"/>
    <policy-marker vocabulary="1" code="1" significance="0">
      <narrative>Gender Equality</narrative>
    </policy-marker>
    <policy-marker vocabulary="1" code="2" significance="0">
      <narrative>Aid to Environment</narrative>
    </policy-marker>
    <policy-marker vocabulary="1" code="3" significance="2">
      <narrative>Participatory Development/Good Governance</narrative>
    </policy-marker>
    <policy-marker vocabulary="1" code="4" significance="0">
      <narrative>Trade Development</narrative>
    </policy-marker>
    <policy-marker vocabulary="1" code="5" significance="0">
      <narrative>Aid Targeting the Objectives of the Convention on Biological Diversity</narrative>
    </policy-marker>
    <policy-marker vocabulary="1" code="6" significance="0">
      <narrative>Aid Targeting the Objectives of the Framework Convention on Climate Change - Mitigation</narrative>
    </policy-marker>
    <policy-marker vocabulary="1" code="7" significance="0">
      <narrative>Aid Targeting the Objectives of the Framework Convention on Climate Change - Adaptation</narrative>
    </policy-marker>
    <policy-marker vocabulary="1" code="8" significance="0">
      <narrative>Aid Targeting the Objectives of the Convention to Combat Desertification</narrative>
    </policy-marker>
    <collaboration-type code="3"/>
    <default-flow-type code="10"/>
    <default-finance-type code="110"/>
    <related-activity ref="XM-DAC-6-4-011077" type="1"/>
    </iati-activity>
```

Expected output:

```
<iati-activity>
  <iati-identifier>XM-DAC-6-4-011077</iati-identifier>
  <reporting-org ref="XM-DAC-6-4" type="10" secondary-reporter="0">
      <narrative xml:lang="it">AICS - Agenzia Italiana per la Cooperazione allo Sviluppo</narrative>
  <narrative>Italian Agency for Development Cooperation</narrative>
  <title>
      <narrative>Protracted relief and recovery operation</narrative>
      <narrative xml:lang="it">Protracted relief and recovery operation 
      </narrative>
  </title>
  <description>
      <narrative>Protracted relief and recovery operation</narrative>
  </description>
</iati-activity>

... next XML starts with next <iati-identifier>
```

Current output:

```
<iati-activity>
  <iati-identifier>XM-DAC-6-4-011077</iati-identifier>
  <reporting-org ref="XM-DAC-6-4" type="10" secondary-reporter="0">
      </reporting-org>
  <narrative xml:lang="it">AICS - Agenzia Italiana per la Cooperazione allo Sviluppo</narrative>
  <narrative>Italian Agency for Development Cooperation</narrative>
  <title>
      </title>
  <narrative>Protracted relief and recovery operation</narrative>
  <narrative xml:lang="it">Protracted relief and recovery operation </narrative>
  <description>
      </description>
  <narrative>Protracted relief and recovery operation</narrative>
</iati-activity>
```

Comment: 1) Please show us the contents of the input file (activity-list(2).xml). 2) What you have under "Expected" looks like a single file. But you say that you want several output files.

Comment: @mzjn it has been edited now with a bigger sample (it repeats after this point, and it is a lot of data so I'm not sure if it'd be okay to post the full content here?)

Comment: Well, what you should try to do is to provide a [mcve]. Trim everything down to the smallest pieces of code and XML that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @mzjn Then this definiteliy qualifies! The XML should be split once it reaches that <iati-identifier> node, and the biggest issue itself right now is the way in which it is being written, as it is splitting properly (the new file is written once it reaches the iati-identifier node)

Comment: Is what you have below "Current" the input file? It is still unclear.

Comment: @mzjn Correct, "Current" is the input file. I have edited the initial post for clarity, thank you.

Comment: Where in Current XML does `XM-DAC-6-4-011077` show up as `<iati-identifier>`? Desired output must align to input.

Comment: @Parfait My apologies, I messed up by trying to workout the character limit max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a parameterized [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/) to split your large input source into individual XML files by `<iati-identifier>` nodes. Python's `lxml` can run XSLT 1.0 scripts and even pass parameter values from application layer to stylesheet (not unlike passing parameters in the other declarative, special-purpose language -SQL).

Specifically, Python can iteratively pass the position of each `iati-identifier` after running an XPath (sibling to XSLT) for total count of nodes in document. The `following-sibling::node_name[1]` is used to get first adjacent node by name.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special.xml file)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- XSL PARAM -->
    <xsl:param name="item_num"/>

    <xsl:template match="/iati-activity">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="iati-identifier[position()=$item_num]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="iati-identifier">
        <iati-activity>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::reporting-org[1]"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::narrative[1]"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::title[1]"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::description[1]"/>
        </iati-activity>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# LOAD XML AND XSL SCRIPT
xml = ET.parse('Input.xml')
xsl = ET.parse('Script.xsl')
transform = ET.XSLT(xsl)

# LOOP THROUGH ALL NODE COUNTS AND PASS PARAMETER TO XSLT
iati_count = len(xml.xpath('//iati-identifier'))

for i in range(iati_count):
   n = ET.XSLT.strparam(str(i+1))            
   result = transform(xml, item_num=n)         # NAME OF XSL PARAMETER

   # SAVE XML TO FILE
   with open('Output_{}.xml'.format(i+1), 'wb') as f:
       f.write(result)
```

---

#### Outputs

**Output_1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<iati-activity>
  <iati-identifier>XM-DAC-6-4-011077</iati-identifier>
  <reporting-org ref="XM-DAC-6-4" type="10" secondary-reporter="0">
    <narrative xml:lang="it">AICS - Agenzia Italiana per la Cooperazione allo Sviluppo</narrative>
    <narrative>Italian Agency for Development Cooperation</narrative>
  </reporting-org>
  <title>
    <narrative>Protracted relief and recovery operation</narrative>
    <narrative xml:lang="it">Protracted relief and recovery operation </narrative>
  </title>
  <description>
    <narrative>Protracted relief and recovery operation</narrative>
  </description>
</iati-activity>
```

**Output_2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<iati-activity>
  <iati-identifier>XM-DAC-6-4-011077-01-0</iati-identifier>
  <reporting-org ref="XM-DAC-6-4" type="10" secondary-reporter="0">
    <narrative xml:lang="it">AICS - Agenzia Italiana per la Cooperazione allo Sviluppo</narrative>
    <narrative>Italian Agency for Development Cooperation</narrative>
  </reporting-org>
  <title>
    <narrative>Protracted relief and recovery operation</narrative>
    <narrative xml:lang="it">Protracted relief and recovery operation</narrative>
  </title>
  <description>
    <narrative>The scope of the program is to support the population on food security and resilience. In particular, to support local agricultural products and vulnerable families on food security.</narrative>
  </description>
</iati-activity>
```

Comment: Thank you, this has worked like a charm and provided me new knowledge regarding XSL which I had no idea about!